# How can I use Intent in postDelayed using Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, postdelayed

This is for a splash screen. I've followed the tutorial but it's still not working. It keeps on getting an error.

This is my code:

```
package id.ac.umn.finalproject;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent startApp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PemasukanActivity.class);

        new Handler().postDelayed(startActivity(startApp), 3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin try this:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
           Intent startApp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PemasukanActivity.class);
          startActivity(startApp)
        }, 3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to create a Splash screen is as follows

style.xml

```
 <style name="SplashStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>
```

Splash.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/black" /> // background color

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> // logo
        android:gravity="center" />

</layer-list>
```

Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashStyle">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash); // No need setContentView
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```